# useState não atualiza

Tags: react

tenho uma função que busca informações de um usuário em uma API e armazena em um useState, gostaria de saber pq se coloco um console.log pra ver se armazenou os dados corretamente no useState me retorna vazio porém na tela me mostra os valores só a partir da segunda requisição é mostrado as informações no console, vou postar o código aqui:

````
export default function Teste() {

  const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState({});
  const [nome, setNome] = useState()

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const auxValues = { ...nome }
    auxValues[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    setNome(auxValues)
  }

  function buscarUser(cpf){
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/user/${cpf}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setRepositories(data));
  }

  function handleUser(){
    buscarUser(nome.usuario)
    console.log(repositories)
  }

  return(
    <>
      <input name="usuario" onChange={handleChange}></input>
      <button onClick={ handleUser }>Buscar User</button>
      <label> {repositories.nome} </label>
    </>
  ) 
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo dar uma olhada em `promises` e também um pouco a respeito sobre `programação assíncrona` no `Javascript`, explicando de maneira geral, o que está acontecendo ai é que na sua função `handleUser`, você está executando a `buscarUser` no qual é uma `promise` e a mesma não está sendo esperada o termino da sua execução para realizar o `console.log`, uma maneira simples de resolver isso seria simplesmente colocar:

```js
function handleUser(){
    buscarUser(nome.usuario)
     .then(() => console.log(repositories))
 }
```

Dessa maneira o `console.log` somente será executado quando a requisição terminar e for bem sucedida. Espero te ajudado ! Abraços !

Comment: Alterei a função conforme sua sugestão, porém no log continua aparecendo o objeto vazio mas código html aparece os dados de boa, enfim já coloquei as functions como async mesmo assim sem sucesso. Enfim como esta renderizando de boa no html não esta "por enquanto " interferindo no sistema, mas só queria entender do pq isso acontece. Mas obrigado pela sugestão e ajuda.

Comment: uma das possíveis respostas, seria que antes do `React` chamar a funçāo `setState`, está fazendo o `console.log` no qual está printando um objeto vazio que é o estado inicial. Você poderia mudar esse `console.log` para a funçāo `buscarUser`, logo após finalizar a requisiçāo. Depois da uma lida no Ciclo de eventos do React: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html